# How to test IOS 6 on XCode 7 El Capitan?

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode7, xcode4.5

I am not an IOS developer. I have a Cordova app with two small errors on IOS6. The app has been compiled in Xcode 7.2 on El Capitan usign the following configuration:

[image: deployment target]

[image]

The app compiles and works ok on an IPhone 3GS device running IOS 6.1.6; however, our customer has found some errors on an IPhone 4 running IOS 6.0.

I don't have any device like that. I tried to install an old version of the simulator that crashed my XCode so I had to reinstall it.

Then I decided to try on a Mountain Lion virtual machine running XCode 4.5. I copied the project and tried to execute it to find this error:

```
Failed to load project at '/Users/holamundo2/Desktop/IOS_original/isosmed/platforms/ios/holamundo2.xcodeproj', incompatible project version. I don't know how to make the project "compatible".
```

Finally, I even tried wildly to copy from the simulator in El capitan to the simulator in the Virtual machine. Obviously, it didn't work either.

[image]

So I have two questions:

**1. How can I change an Xcode project created from XCode 7 to one I can run from my virtual machine?**

**2. Is there any other way to copy/paste one simulator image to another in order to run the application?**

Comment: Honestly, you should not as a developer be supporting iOS6 anymore.  Take a look at this site:

https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/

As of today, 79% are iOS9, 16% are iOS8, and only 5% are iOS7 or below.  I suspect of that 5% most are iOS7 not 6.  It doesn't make sense to support an OS that has been obsolete since September 18, 2013.

Comment: try to download Xcode 5 or Xcode 6 from the apple developer page and open the project using one of that versions

Comment: Thank you. jcsearmobile, I already did that, on Xcode 6 there is no Iphone 4 simulator running IOS6, Xcode 5 doesn't work on El Capitan, that's why I tried on a virtual machine.

Comment: DShaw, I also talked to the customer about this issue, maybe, if I am lucky, there will be no more support to that version of IOS.